# Define macro error: expected primary-exception before 'asm'

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, macros, breakpoints

This code is supposed to provide an assert function, for debugging only, where it automatically creates a breakpoint if the assert fails (not the full code):

```
#define DebugInt3 asm __volatile__ (".byte 0x90CC")
#define DEBUG_ASSERT(expr) ((expr)? ((void)0): (DebugInt3))
```

However, I get these errors:

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'asm'
error: expected ')' before 'asm'
error: expected ')' before ';' token
```

What I find confusing is that "asm **volatile** (".byte 0x90CC")" works if I directly put it in the main function. Stackoverflow removes the double underscores to make the word bold by the way. What am I doing wrong?

Solution and example, thanks Richard Pennington:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#ifdef DEBUG
// 0xCC - int 3 - breakpoint
// 0x90 - nop?
#define DebugInt3 asm __volatile__ (".byte 0x90CC")
#define DEBUG_ASSERT(expr) do { if (!(expr)) DebugInt3; } while(false)
#endif

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        DEBUG_ASSERT(false);
    //    assert(false);
    #endif // DEBUG

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, and what's the actual context it was used please??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a statement as an expression. Try something like

```
#define DEBUG_ASSERT(expr) do { if (!(expr)) DebugInt3; } while(0)
```

Comment: Why the do {...} while(true)? I saw that somewhere else and don't quite understand the necessity of a loop.

Comment: It's while(0), i.e. do it once. And it's there so you can put a semicolon after the macro. And also it is a convenient way to hide local variables if they are needed.

Comment: Ohhhhh so there are no way to declare a scope with, for example, two brackets?